# AC Condensate not draining from newish HVAC

Tags: air-conditioning

A few years ago I replaced my entire HVAC system with one similar size to my old one. I used a local contractor that I've had a long relationship with, who I've continued a maintenance contract with. For quite a while, I had a vague feeling that condensate wasn't coming out the pipe near my backdoor that had released quite a bit of water with the previous unit. This year's it's been more humid than ever, and I made a point to check on the drain pipe at multiple times you would expect condensate - and nothing. I asked the technician about it during my last check under the contract and he said he poured water in the pipe and it comes out so the drain is fine; and when I pressed him about where the moisture was going, he replied that the blower is probably drying up all the moisture. Does this make sense? I've had loads of water issues in my crawl space that I've been working hard to address and don't want to add to it with the AC. Should I call the management for another look, or hire another contractor to check it out?

Comment: Can you take a picture showing where the condensate line is attached to the air handler?

Answer (score 1):

If the drain works with water poured in it it is clear and his professional opinion sounds correct. If the water did not drain or there was water damage there would be a problem. My guess at this point is the new system is a higher efficiency unit with a better balanced evaporator so it may not produce as much water as a less efficient model. The big difference in newer units is the evaporator is not having the extremes of cold that creates more condensation due to the larger temp extremes of older units but creates the same btu's per hour by managing the Freon usually with a temperature controlled throttle valve where many older systems used a simple orifice. The throttle valve is a better way to keep the evaporator at a constant temp where the orifice has no feedback ant the evaporator temp gets colder while the compressor is running. This may be the reason you do not see the amount of water due to the tighter control.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ed! This is helpful. I've always trusted this contractor but needed some reassurance. It's difficult to tell if there's water damage because I have other unrelated issues I've been working hard to address in this same area to the crawlspace below.